# Multiple intercept method in RecordInterceptor Spring Framework Kafka Listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a class, that implements RecordInterceptor. Reading the documentation from [Spring-Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/RecordInterceptor.html) there is a method called intercept which takes 2 parameter, the Record and the Consumer. However for some reason my IDE (Intellij) asks me to implements this method, which should be deprecated:

```
@Deprecated
@Nullable
ConsumerRecord<K, V> intercept(ConsumerRecord<K, V> var1);
```

Why is it that I have to implement this deprecated method? Moreover, when I try to implement the abstract method (shown below), it is not called:

```
@Nullable  
default ConsumerRecord<K, V> intercept(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record, Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
  return this.intercept(record);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on Spring for Apache Kafka version which cannot break its backward compatibility. Therefore that `intercept(ConsumerRecord<K, V> var1)` is still there.

We cannot make it as `default` and enforce you to implement that new one, since it is going to break a backward compatibility and enforce all those who are already in support mode.

You simply can upgrade your project to the latest Spring for Apache Kafka version.

I don't see how that new API is not called.
The only places where this `RecordInterceptor` is used is `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` with the logic like:

```
        if (this.recordInterceptor != null) {
            record = this.recordInterceptor.intercept(record, this.consumer);
        }
```

So, it might not be called because you don't inject it into such a listener container.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. That new API is actually called. Thanks!